# Value returned changes original passed value

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, parameter-passing

So I am writing a main function that passes two char values into five different char* functions one by one, but when I return the value of it, it completely changes my value; how would I fix this?

For example:

Passing char one into my function, myStrCat, returns world! since that is what my function does (btw, the assignment is how to code specific library functions without any library imports). But not only does it return it, it changes it. So when I pass one into the next function down, it will return the wrong value as one (Hello ) isn't being passed, instead two (World!) is.

```
char one[size] = "Hello ";
char two[size] = "World!";
cout << "strlen: " << myStrLen(one) << endl;
cout << "strcat: " << myStrCat(one, two) << endl;
```

Word function is being passed into

```
char* myStrCat(char inputOne[], char inputTwo[]){
    int sizeOne = myStrLen(inputOne);
    int sizeTwo = myStrLen(inputTwo);
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeTwo; i++){
        inputOne[i + sizeOne] = inputTwo[i];
    } 

    return inputOne;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your function's code? it sounds like you have a side effect in your function which edits the value of your function parameter....

Comment: Added it @RannLifshitz